# mobile network and Wi-Fi are blocking

Tags: samsung, samsung-galaxy-s-2, mobile-network

The problem of my phone is, mobile network and also Wi-Fi connection are sometimes blocking. it happens randomly. On the screen, it shows everything is regular and there are connections, however, if I try to connect to network/Wi-Fi, it fails. The only solution is to restart the phone. Do you know what is the problem? I guess old rom....

My phone is [Samsung Galaxy s II lite (AKA Samsung I9070 Galaxy S Advance)](http://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_i9070_galaxy_s_advance-4469.php).

Model number: GT-I9070

Baseband version: I9070BULK1

Android ver: 2.3.6

Kernel: 2.6.35.7-1211698

Build number: GINGERBREAD.BULK1

Comment: What do you mean by "are blocking" and "it fails"? What do you actually see on the screen? Since we can't see your phone, try to be precise.

Comment: I mean the connection is blocked. There is no access to network. for instance I cannot send sms or make a phone call. Same for internet access: I cannot use Whatsapp or connect to a website.

Comment: On screen, I dont see anything special. everything seems working, there is no error massage.

Comment: feel free to modify the question to make it more cleaer

Comment: Did you try factory reset?

Answer (score 0):

This issue happens for many models.

Let me say a simple scenario

You are in a call, suddenly the signal has gone and call drops. Then even waiting for a long time, the signal is not coming.

This is because, the phone didn't attempt to connect to a network anymore.

The solutions

1. Turn on airplane mode and after 5-10 seconds, turn off it.
2. Go to operator selection -> manual -> search and choose the operator, later change to automatic.
3. As you said, restart the phone.

Comment: do you know any solution that fix this issue forever? this workaround has to be performed every time manually.

Comment: In my knowledge, there is no permanent solution. This is because the phone is not aware of the disconnection as it happend suddenly.

Comment: Do you have any list of models with this problem?

Comment: I found this happens on micromax, yureka and some small brands but never found this on htc or samsung. In samsung, data connection goes but the cellular network is available. Mainly in Android 5+ or CM 12+. But I can't state only these models. This is my knowledge in this issue